# CRM365 - What is the easiest way to get list 1:M entity relations

Tags: entity, crm, lookup, dynamics-crm-365

Is there way (plugin to XrmToolBox, code fragment) to get the list of lookup attributes pointing to my entity? I need exactly the same list as in FetchXML Builder plugin, link-entity Relationship 1:M (see the picture) and be able to copy this list.
(My entity is opportunity)

[image]

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You can achieve this using [RetrieveRelationshipRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/metadata-relationshipmetadata).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the list to copy and paste, you can get this in the browser using CRM's WebAPI

`/api/data/v9.0/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata?$select=SchemaName&$filter=ReferencedEntity eq 'account'`

This query is doing the following:

- Retrieves all 1:N relationships from CRM
- Limiting the number of attributes returned to only include `Schemaname`
- Filtering the result to only show attributes targeting the `account` entity

You just open your CRM organization in the browser and paste the above line after your CRM's address

e.g.

> [https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata?$select=SchemaName&$filter=ReferencedEntity eq 'account'](https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata?$select=SchemaName&$filter=ReferencedEntity%20eq%20'account')

Answer (score 0):

As Filburt show me the right way, possible C# solution is in the bottom

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetRelatedEntities (string entityName)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> retval = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    RetrieveEntityRequest retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
    {
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
        LogicalName = entityName 
    };
    RetrieveEntityResponse retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest);

    OneToManyRelationshipMetadata[] relations = retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse.EntityMetadata.OneToManyRelationships;
    foreach(OneToManyRelationshipMetadata m in relations)
    {
        retval.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.ReferencingEntity, m.ReferencingAttribute));
    }

    return retval;
}
```